# Adding topics and subscriptions via a script to my Azure queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-powershell

I have been manually adding topics and subscriptions to my queue via the Azure portal. Is it possible to use a script to create these? If so, can anyone advise on what I should be searching on as my searches seem to bring up very old blogs and nothing specific to creating queue topics etc

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few solutions. If you want to write code, have a look here:

> The Azure Service Bus management libraries can dynamically provision Service Bus namespaces and entities. This enables complex deployments and messaging scenarios, and makes it possible to programmatically determine what entities to provision. These libraries are currently available for .NET.
>
> **Supported functionality**
>   Namespace creation, update, deletion
>   Queue creation, update, deletion
>   Topic creation, update, deletion
>   Subscription creation, update, deletion

Find more information on [Service Bus management libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-management-libraries)

If you're more into scripting (as far as PowerShell can be considered scripting), you can also [Use PowerShell to manage Service Bus resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-manage-with-ps)